# Web page is not getting loaded in Cypress browser

Tags: typescript, cypress

Web page is not getting loaded in cypress associated browser including Chrome, Electron, Edge, and when I try to run it in any browser, it's working fine.

Web page using Web sockets MQTT request and ttf fonts, I am also passing all default launch arguments with chrome browser, still, it's getting stuck at 95%,

I don't have the sample code for web site, still this is what I trying to do:

```js
cy.visit('/');
cy.get('input[type=email]').type('{selectall}').clear().type('rachit24@gmail.com');
cy.get('input[type=password]').type('{selectall}').clear().type('password@{enter}');
```

also this is getting loaded in cypress Firefox browser, but it's not feasible for me also, because every time I need to set the auto proxy settings in browser while loading the test case.
Otherwise it's showing me Network Error in cypress Firefox browser

Comment: Your question doesn't give enough information. Please add an example code that fails and a snapshot of the final cypress state

Comment: @RosenMihaylov, it's a strange issue that I am facing, my webpage is getting loaded in any normal browser and when I try to do the same with cypress browser for example chrome, it's not getting loaded 

I am passing default launch arguments with cypress chrome, and not sure why it's not able to load the web page 
Is there any way I can debug the browser, or pass extra arguments to resolve this 

I also checked in network tab, all request are getting completed.

Comment: I don't have the sample code for web site, still this is what I trying to do 

  cy.visit('/')
        cy.get('input[type=email]').type('{selectall}').clear().type('rachit24@gmail.com')
        cy.get('input[type=password]').type('{selectall}').clear().type('password@{enter}')

Comment: also this is getting loaded in cypress firefox browser, but it's not feasible for me also, because every time I need to set the auto proxy settings in browser while loading the test case. 

other wise it's showing me Network Error in cypress firefox browser

Comment: What is the error? Can you show a snapshot of it and the full stack trace? `cy.visit('/')` works only if you had set the website in `cypress.json` as a `baseUrl` variable or if you used at least once a `cy.visit('fullPageUrl')`. I prefer to always use `cy.visit('fullPageUrl')`

Comment: yes I also tried using cy.visit('fullPageUrl'),  it's the same in both cases 

cy.visit opens up the login page, and after putting credentials to login, I am going to the after login page, and that page is not getting loaded

there is no stack track as such and showing no error in console, it is just waiting on the progress bar

Comment: In our project for local runs we need to start different consoles and xampp. May be you forgot to start one needed?

Comment: the web page is completely running on remote domain and public website, and same time it's getting loaded in normal browser, but having some trouble with cypress assoicated browser